# DateDiff within the same column of 2 records with a JOIN and WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, datediff

Here is the data:
TABLE 1:

```
usernum|username
-------|--------
1      |JBlow
-------|--------
2      |CFarley
```

TABLE 2:

```
usernum|logdate                |actionnum |extrainfo1
-------|-----------------------|----------|-----------
1      |2016-06-27 10:36:55.033| 202      |50
-------|-----------------------|----------|-----------
1      |2016-06-27 10:40:37.800| 266      |8
-------|-----------------------|----------|-----------
2      |2016-06-27 10:43:18.817| 202      |23
-------|-----------------------|----------|-----------
2      |2016-06-27 10:48:32.413| 266      |7
```

What I am trying to do is join the tables on 'Usernum' so that I can grab the username within the result.

Next, I want to use datediff to calculate the time in minutes between the logdates in table 2. Each entry in table 2 has an actionnum associated with it. In this case, I want to find the difference between the logdate associated with actionnum 202(start) and the logdate associated with actionnum 266(end).

I also want to include the extrainfo1 from only the 202 actionnum rows.

The final result I am looking for will have the following columns:
username, {datediff result}, extrainfo1

Here is a query I came up with that will show the username, logdate, extrainfo1, and actionnum. I've tried the datediff function with a subquery and have not been able to get it to work but I'm no expert.

```
SELECT a.username, b.logdate, b.extrainfo1 AS 'DocumentCount', b.actionnum
FROM hsi.useraccount a
    LEFT JOIN hsi.scanninglog b
    ON a.usernum = b.usernum
WHERE b.actionnum = 266
OR b.actionnum = 202
GROUP BY a.username,b.logdate, b.extrainfo1, b.actionnum
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: it means you have only two records , 1      |2016-06-27 10:36:55.033| 202      |50
-------|-----------------------|----------|-----------
1      |2016-06-27 10:40:37.800| 266      |8 cos im just thinking how about if it is 3 record on the list

Answer (score 0):

One method uses two joins:

```
SELECT ua.*, sls.*,
       dateadiff(day, sls.logdate, sle.logdate) as diff_in_days
FROM hsi.useraccount ua LEFT JOIN
     hsi.scanninglog sls
     ON ua.usernum = sls.usernum AND sls.actionnum = 202 LEFT JOIN
     hsi.scanninglog sle
     ON ua.usernum = sle.usernum AND sle.actionnum = 266;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired query should look like this. I joined twice on `hsi.scanninglog` to represent the start and end log.

```
SELECT 
    a.username 'Username', 
    CASE
        WHEN c.logdate IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE datediff(minute, b.logdate, c.logdate)
    END 'Login Duration', 
    b.extrainfo 'Extra Info'
FROM
    hsi.useraccount a
    LEFT JOIN hsi.scanninglog b
        ON b.usernum = a.usernum AND b.actionnum = 266 -- Start
    LEFT JOIN hsi.scanninglog c
        ON c.usernum = a.usernum AND c.actionnum = 202 -- END
GROUP BY
    a.username,
    b.extrainfo
```

Comment: Thank you, this is close. The issue with this query is I need to incorporate the "Group By" string from my example above so that the data is organized in the correct manner BEFORE the datediff function is run.

Comment: @Fryguy22 updated my answer. I got too focused on the sample data you've provided and didn't notice the `extrainfo` values. Guess there will be cases for more than 2 records for a user in the `scanninglog` but with different `extrainfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
select a.usernum,minlog,maxlog,datediff(minute,minlog,maxlog) as diff from
(select usernum,min(logdate) as minlog from tbl_log group by usernum) as a
left join
(select usernum,max(logdate) as maxlog from tbl_log group by usernum) as b
on a.usernum = b.usernum
```

you can change minute, or day in date diff its depend on yours.
Hope it helps